# Zoom out viewport

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a zoom out on the viewport to .8 for heights bellow 1080.

So far I've done this:

HTML HEAD

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-height:1079px){
    @viewport {
        width: device-width;
        zoom: .8;
    }
}
```

No prefix since I'm using firefox to test it.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned Firefox, the problem is that Firefox, as of versoin 37, [does not support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport#Browser_compatibility) the `@viewport` at rule. Since Firefox has a unresolved [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747754) on the issue from 2012, you might want to try an alternative such as reducing `font-size` to `.8em`.

If you check the Firefox console, you will see this css error:

[image: Unrecognized at-rule or error parsing at-rule '@viewport'.]